# How to get Average search volume AND Average CPC with same Google Adwords API service?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am using the Google Adwords API to retrieve the Average search volume for a given keyword, using the [TargetingIdeaService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService.html) [get function](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService.html#get).
Now I would like to also retrieve the Average CPC for the same keyword.

All I could find so far is a way to do that with the [TrafficEstimatorService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TrafficEstimatorService.html), but that implies additional cost, I believe.

So my question is: is there any way to retrieve *both*:

- the Average Search Volume,
- the CPC data

using the *same* service (either TargetingIdeaService or TrafficEstimatorService, or other)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need to use the TIS to get search volume and the TES to get CPC estimates.  There is no service that provides both.

P.S. - In case you aren't aware, there is an official AdWords API forum: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/forum.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I also posted my question on the API forum but I just favor the stackoverflow format. The Google help forum really need to move to a stackoverflow Q&A format IMO.

Answer (score 3):

This may have been the case at one point but is certainly possible now.  You have to request that information in the requestedAttributesTypes.

`$selector->requestedAttributeTypes = array('KEYWORD_TEXT', 'SEARCH_VOLUME', 'AVERAGE_CPC');`